# Redirect Raw console output in separate program C#

Tags: c#, console

I know you can use something like the following to receive output from one program. However, if that program uses RAW mode output (like a progress bar) how do I display that in my own programs output?

```
var proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = cmdPath;

// set up output redirection
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;    
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
// see below for output handler
proc.ErrorDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;
proc.OutputDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;

proc.Start();

proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "RAW mode like" app ?

Comment: Robocopy for example, will display a percentage of completion. Every time it updates the percentage, it doesn't print out a new line. It just edits an already printed line to display the new value.

Comment: Ha! If i understood your question, it should depend on what process you run and how it communicates with caller, if it communicates at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```